# How I can make typed letters to appear in a row, one after another?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**Plain JavaScript only**

How I can make typed letters to appear in a row, one after another on the page without next letter erasing the previous one? Also I need maximum 9 letters in a row thereafter the row should erase all typed letters.

```js
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your guesses so far :" +
    letter;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Your guesses so far :</p>
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `<input type="text">` (which you autofocus if that's your problem)?

Comment: Because I'm noob I assume ,and also I need the letters in the raw disappear after 9 typed letters.  I just started with JS so it gives me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Oh, you can remove letters at the front by doing `input.value = input.value.slice(-9)`, but you really should use an input for usability. Then start by enhancing it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, simply append the pressed key to the element's `innerHTML`. Your current implementation was simply assigning the `innerHTML` to the original string plus the inputted letter, so you'll see the newly inputted letter replacing the previously inputted letter.

To prevent the entry of more than nine characters, simply check the length of `innerHTML` compared to the length of the original string plus 9. I'd try to keep the HTML on the same line, as when you new line it the preceding spaces are included in the length, and you will need to adjust the if condition accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/2n4bLh9q/2/